# Why won't my calls to date.ToString() and str.Length in C# work together?

Tags: c#, json, string, webmatrix, asp.net-webpages

I realize that this is probably going to be a newbish question, but no matter what I try or lookup, I can't seem to find any answer to why I can't trim some strings like I would want for a json string.

This page is reached via AJAX request, queries a database, and tries to compile a json string that will end up being parsed into a json object that is an array of objects. Sounds simple enough...

What I have now:

```
foreach (var row in db.Query(selectQueryString))
{
    jsonString += "{";
    jsonString += "\"title\":\"" + Json.Encode(row.title) + "\",";
    jsonString += "\"dateNumber\":\"" + Json.Encode(row.eventDate.ToString().Substring(0, row.eventDate.ToString().IndexOf("/"))) + "\",";
    jsonString += "\"dateMonth\":\"" + Json.Encode(row.eventDate.ToString().Substring(row.eventDate.ToString().IndexOf("/"), row.eventDate.ToString().LastIndexOf("/"))) + "\",";
    jsonString += "\"dateYear\":\"" + Json.Encode(row.eventDate.ToString().Substring(row.eventDate.ToString().LastIndexOf("/"), row.eventDate.ToString().Length)) + "\",";
    jsonString += "\"summary\":\"" + Json.Encode(row.summary) + "\",";
    jsonString += "},";
}
```

**Exception Details: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index and length must refer to a location within the string.** *errors on the line that includes 'dateYear'*

All I want to do is end up with a long json string by the end of this, but I can't seem to stop getting errors.

Comment: Please please please don't build JSON manually using `ToString` calls, `Json.Encode` and string concatenation. Consider using [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx). You could simply do `JToken.FromObject(new { /* your fields */ }).ToString()`.

Comment: @TimothyShields Why shouldn't I do it this way? The syntax checks out.

Comment: @TimothyShields Also, there is a big reason why I would do it one way over the other. I understand one way and not the other.

Comment: Because `JToken.FromObject(new { row.title, row.summary, /*etc*/ }).ToString()` is infinitely cleaner and less error prone. You're rewriting the "JSON serialization" operation *every time* you want to serialize objects to JSON.

Comment: Also, just to prove my point: your're putting an extra comma after the `summary` property, even though that's *technically* against the [JSON specifications](http://json.org/) (though most parsers will be forgiving - specifically because certain people like yourself insist on rewriting JSON serialization only to get it wrong).

Comment: @TimothyShields Well, unfortunately I do not know how to use JSON.NET, nor do I wish to lengthen the time for the completion of this project by learning, yet another sytax (for the plug-in, external resource, or whatever it is). As for the errors in syntax, yes, I have noticed them and corrected them. That's what testing is for. At the time of this question, these errors hadn't been debugged yet. I have not noticed any speed or functionality issues resulting from this, yet. Thanks for the advice, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter you pass in a substring should be the number of characters you want back, but you are passing in the total length of the string that you want a substring of.

EDIT:
If it's a year you're trying to get back that second parameter should be 4 I reckon:

```
Json.Encode(row.eventDate.ToString().Substring(row.eventDate.ToString().LastIndexOf("/"), 4))
```

Comment: Apparently it's been a while since I have done a lot of string slicing in C#. Thanks and sry for the dumb question.